# Parsing tweets seperated by tab to csv, tweet text contains tab, how to keep in single column?

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter

I wrote a simple python script to parse Twitter data.  However, I have a problem  that some user put what appear to be a tab in their tweet, and then my script thinks it's a new column, and parses it as such.  I would like to know the best way in Python to force the tweet text to be all contained in one column.

****Example****

```
465853965351927808  AhmedAlKhalifa_ RT @Milanello: Another photo of how Casa Milan looks now after the color treatment is done:
#ForzaMilan http://t.co/p8YaBXpgj1
465853965142597633  AlySnodgrass    RT @LJSanders88: Who's ready for the new reality tv show: "Late Night Shenanigans!" Starring- Ozark Seniors and co-starring- the Law Enfo…
465853965289422849  amandafaang oh i see! we should meet up w all the bx-ians soon haha — yess! http://t.co/Isdg7hjYbV
465853964786089985  isla_galloway_x RT @fuxkchan: Tomorrowland is defo on the bucket list
465853965515493376  usptz   7 o'clock in the morning
465853965385482240  Orapinploy  RT @FolkFunFine: I want to see the blue sky
465853965297790976  Khansheeren My answer to What on the internet made you smile today? http://t.co/TQKBJeOx4b
465853965150998528  khenDict    Ah almost left the house without seeing khaya...ah guys warn me next time!!!!
#YOUTVLIVE
#YOUTVLIVE
#YOUTVLIVE
465853965310382080  1987Lukyanova   Мое новое достижение `Больш...`. Попробуй превзойти меня в The Tribez для #Android! http://t.co/HWEQQloFWB #androidgames, #gameinsight
```

**Code:**

```
import json
import sys

def main():

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()

        data = []

        try:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
        except ValueError as detail:
            continue

        for tweet in data:

            ## deletes any rate limited data
            if tweet.has_key('limit'):
                pass

            else:
                print "\t".join([
                tweet['id_str'],
                tweet['user']['screen_name'],
                tweet['text']
                ]).encode('utf8')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than generating the TSV file manually, use the `csv` module, which will take care of escaping any literal tabs for you. The `codecs` module can be used to automatically encode the text for you as it is written to standard output.

```
import json
import sys
import csv
import codecs

def main():

    writer = csv.writer(codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout), delimiter="\t")
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()

        data = []

        try:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
        except ValueError as detail:
            continue

        for tweet in data:

            ## deletes any rate limited data
            if tweet.has_key('limit'):
                pass

            else:
                writer.writerow([
                tweet['id_str'],
                tweet['user']['screen_name'],
                tweet['text']
                ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: excellent idea, thanks!  I believe I need to tweak the encoding section somehow, as I'm getting the following error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 139: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: can you, or anyone else, help me figure out the UnicodeError?  I understand the problem, and have tried everything that I come across to properly encode the data, but still no luck.